# Checking if a number is prime using fork and pipe

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

So I have to do the next program:
create a child process,
the parent reads numbers from the keyboard (until 0) and sends them to the child,
the child receives numbers from the parent and prints those that are prime,
when the child receives 0 from the parent, it will terminate.

And I did it the next way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
        int a=1;
        int isprime=0;
        int p[2];
        pipe(p);

        int pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
                exit(1);
        if(pid == 0)
        {
                close(p[1]);
                read(p[0],&a,sizeof(int));
                isprime = 1;
                for(int i=2;i*i<=a;i++)
                        if(a%i==0)
                                isprime = 0;
                if(isprime == 1)
                        printf("%d is prime",a);
                close(p[0]);
        }
        else
        {
                close(p[0]);
                while(a!=0){
                        printf("a=");
                        scanf("%d",&a);
                        write(p[1],&a,sizeof(int));
                }
                wait(0);
                close(p[1]);

        }

        return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work properly, it stops after the first reading of a. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You should always check the return value of your function calls. What does `write` return on second call? Does it return an error value? What does it indicate? Who is supposed to read the second value? There is no loop in the consumer process.

Comment: You need a loop around the reading and prime-finding code in the child.

Comment: The child only seems to read one number from the pipe at the moment. You need a loop to keep going until `read` returns 0 (indicating end of file) or -1 (indicating an error). Also, it is possible for `read` and `write` to return less than `sizeof(int)`, so you should check for that and call `read` or `write` again to read or write the remaining portion of the `int`.

Comment: `i<=a/i` is better than `i*i<=a`.  OP's code is UB for primes of `a` near `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Prime detection is incorrect for `a < 2`.  Suggest `if(isprime == 1)` --> `if(isprime == 1 && a >= 2)`

Comment: yes, but is a problem about how I structured the code using the pipe, not about the prime algorithm. It reads a number, prints if it is prime or not and then it stops, but I want to do this until i read 0